# Deserialization and object constructor

Tags: .net, deserialization

This is driving me crazy. I have a very simple question. When an object is being deserialized, will any constructor for that class be called? I am observing that none of my constructors are being called!!! I have searched on the net but I did not get any good explanations. Please enlighten me.

**EDIT**

Further to my bewilderment I have noted from net that there are two attributes available OnDeserializing and OnDeserialized. And now I see that they dont apply to constructors. I am confused.

**EDIT2**

Now what is this deserialization constructor that Marc is talking about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18377439/1977871) ?

Comment: Deserialization using what? `BinaryFormatter`? `XmlSerializer`? ProtoBuf.net?

Comment: Its BinaryFormatter. But does that matter?

Comment: Only `BinaryFormatter` for classes implementing [`ISerializable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable(v=vs.110).aspx) expects the `protected ctor(SerializationInfo, StreamingContext)` (see [remarks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2) in the MSDN article). If you use, say, `XmlSerializer`, it will require your class to have a public parameterless constructor (protobuf.net too, likely). Without posting some actual code, it's impossible to know what you are doing.

Comment: In any case, no serialization library will know which constructor to use and how to fill it, so there are two options: 1) a constructor with a specific argument list, or 2) plain parameterless constructor.

Comment: Ok, now I begin to understand. I have not implemented ISerializable. So now the final question(I hope). Does this mean that no constructor will be called in my case since i do not implement ISerializable?

Comment: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2): *Any class that might be serialized must be marked with the `[Serializable]` attribute. If a class **needs to control its serialization process**, it can implement the `ISerializable` interface*. So, if you just want `BinaryFormatter` to copy all your private fields, you don't need to do anything, and no constructor will be called.

Comment: Thanks Groo. Makes sense now. I was puzzled initially by the fact that an object can created without calling any constructor.