# JsonConvert string to Collection

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I get this json format from an API:

```
"url_service": "",
"Description": null,
"Target": "5,6",
"Category ": "2"
```

I'm trying to deserialize the json into a model. The trouble is with the "Target" field which is supposed to be an ICollection of int.
Here is my model:

```
public string Description{ get; set; }
public ICollection<int> Target{ get; set; }
public int Category { get; set; }
```

Is there a way to process the Json before it gets serialised in order to make a collection out of the comma separated string?

Comment: If you use Newtonsoft, you'll probably need to create your own [JsonConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to change the deserialization logic, why not make it easier on yourself and just include a new property in your model?

```
public string Description{ get; set; }
public int Category { get; set; }

//Change this back to string, since that is what your JSON is
public string Target{ get; set; }

//Add a "TargetList" property that just reads from "Target" and turns into a List
public List<int> TargetList => Target.Split(',').Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToList();
```

Be aware that there is no error handling in my code so you will have to modify accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think of making an additional attribute in the model for the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, have your C# class implement the `ISerializable` interface.  There are OnDeserialized(), OnSerialized() functions you could implement.

Refer to [.NET Deserialisation with OnDeserializing and OnDeserialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18377046/net-deserialisation-with-ondeserializing-and-ondeserialized)

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON fragment does not describe a collection of integers but a string. The correct one would be

`"Target": [ 5, 6 ],`

which translates into a JSON schema of

```
 "Target": {
     "type": ["array"],
     "items": { "type": "integer"}
    },
```

---

If you don't have control of the result then create another property which will be a result of integers such as

```
   private string _target;
   public string Target {  get { return _target; } 
                           set { 
                                 _target = value; 
                                 Targets = Regex.Matches(_target, @"(\d+)")
                                                .OfType<Match>()
                                                .Select(mt => int.Parse(mt.Value))
                                                .ToList();
   public List<int> Targets { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Target field is of string type in your json, hence the serialiser will attempt to read it as a string.
You can use a converter to overrule that, for example using [Newtonsoft Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm).

Let's assume your data structure to be defined as follows:

```
public class Data {
    public string Description{ get; set; }
    public ICollection<int> Target{ get; set; }
    public int Category { get; set; }
}
```

Then you may create your own [JsonConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) as follows:

```
public class DataConverter : JsonConverter {

    public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) {

        var jObject = JObject.Load(reader);

        var data = new Data();

        if (jObject.TryGetValue("Description", out JToken jDescription)) {
            data.Description = jDescription.Value<string>();
        }
        if (jObject.TryGetValue("Target", out JToken jTarget)) {
            data.Target = ToTarget(jTarget, serializer);
        }
        if (jObject.TryGetValue("Category", out JToken jCategory)) {
            data.Category = jCategory.Value<int>();
        }

        return req;

    }

    private static ICollection<int> ToTarget( JToken jTarget, JsonSerializer serializer ) {

        int defaultValue = -1;
        var target = new List<int>();
        var collection = jTarget.Value<string>().Split(',');
        foreach (string str in collection)
            if (int.TryParse(str, out int number))
                target.Add(number);
            else
                target.Add(defaultValue);

        return target;

    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => objectType == typeof(Data);

}
```

You can then deserialise using the following code:

```
var jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
jsonSettings.Converters.Add(new DataConverter);
Data data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(yourJsonString, jsonSettings);
```

Further considerations: this approach provides clear separation between your data definition and the data parsing logic, hence keeping your data structure and definition clean from any json specific information and parsing logic.